# Adding JavaScript variables more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, math

If i have two sum variables with total individual variables. Is there an easier way of getting the sum?

Example:

```
var first_one = 5;
var first_two = 5;

var second_one = 5;
var second_two = 5;

var firstTotal = first_one + first_two;
var secondTotal = second_one + second_two;

var total = firstTotal + secondTotal;
return total;
```

Comment: How is that more efficient? It takes longer to type, more bytes to store, and the only way to implement it involves using a function call instead of a simple operator!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a function called `sum()`

```
function sum(val1, val2) {
    return val1 + val2;
}
```

Call it

```
var firstTotal = sum(first_one, first_two);
var secondTotal = sum(second_one, second_two);

var total = sum(firstTotal, secondTotal);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sum(a,b){
      return a+b;
}    
var firstTotal = sum(first_one, first_two);
```